# How to make all figures float on the outer margins of two-side document?

Tags: floats, margins, double-sided, marginpar

I want to make a double-sided problem booklet that contains several questions. Each question has a distinct number and may have zero or more figures. Each figure has a caption and floats on the outer margin. The following figure illustrates what I want to have.

[image]

Is there a document class or package to do this out of the box? If the answer is NO, then how to create such a problem booklet?

Comment: Marginpar can be a "floating object" with some packages/customizasiont. I can't look into that now as I have to leave, but this is a consideration.

Comment: `tufte` class`!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As **tohecz** mentions in his comment, you can use `\marginpar` for your purpose; using `\captionof` (from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages) you can provide the captions.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[outermargin=2cm,innermargin=5cm,marginparwidth=3cm,marginparsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\MarginFig[4][width=\marginparwidth]{%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\captionof{figure}{#3}
\label{#4}}
}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
%\layout
text\MarginFig{name1}{description for figure one}{fig:test1} \lipsum[1-2]\MarginFig{name2}{description for figure one}{fig:test2}
\lipsum[1]\MarginFig[height=7cm,width=\marginparwidth]{name3}{description for figure three}{fig:test3}\lipsum[1-3]
text\MarginFig[height=7cm,width=\marginparwidth]{name4}{description for figure four}{fig:test4} \lipsum[1]\MarginFig{name5}{description for figure five}{fig:test5}\lipsum[2]\MarginFig{name6}{description for figure six}{fig:test6}\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the code above  I used the `\reversemarginpar` command and the `geometry` package to customize the page layout in order to obtain the result shown in the original question (images in the left margin for odd-numbered pages and images in the right margin for even-numbered pages). Those settings are, of course, optional.

Comment: I think I don't need `\reversemarginpar` to meet the requirements in the question, i.e., all figures float on the outer margin.

Comment: @Moderator: OK; I wasn't sure if you needed it or not since your image suggested using the leftmargin for odd pages and the rightmargin for even pages.

Comment: Sorry, is `marginnote` necessary in this case?