# How to make sure the images properly float on the marginpar?

Tags: marginpar

I want to create a problem booklet consisting of some questions and images on the marginpar. How to make sure the images properly float on the marginpar?

If you carefully see the left image below, you will notice that the most bottom image gets cropped as it is not properly floated.

[image][image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=9cm,
    innermargin=2cm,
    marginparwidth=7cm,
    marginparsep=20pt
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\MarginFig[1]{%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{#1}
\label{#1}}}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Higgs Boson}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig{1}
\MarginFig{2}
\MarginFig{3}
\lipsum[1-2]

\item
\MarginFig{4}
\MarginFig{5}
\MarginFig{6}
\lipsum[1-2]

\item 
\MarginFig{7}
\MarginFig{8}
\MarginFig{9}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This question is a continuation of [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53123/9467).

### Edit 3

Bonus questions (without prizes): Among the permutation of 
`\MarginFig{n}`, `\MarginFig{n+1}`, `\MarginFig{n+2}`, and `\lipsum[1-2]`, which one will produce the best floating?

Comment: Is it getting better if you use the `marginfix` package?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Yes. It is getting better. Thanks. You can submit it as your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `marginfix` will help avoid overflows. It doesn't implement any "intelligent" *floating* though, so be prepared for margin images to "pile up" if you are using too many of them.

Comment: Sometimes I get "too many unprocessed floats".

Comment: That's more or less what I meant. `marginfix` will turn marginpars which could not be placed on the current page into floats waiting to be placed on the next page(s). LaTeX allows only a rather limited number of those to float around unplaced.

Comment: Does the permutation of `\MarginFig{xxx}` and `\lipsum[1-2]` matter?

Comment: Not really. Every marginpar gets 'attached' to the line it appears on. So it really only matters how many you use on a page of text and less on the finer order in which they appear.