# How to flow a marginpar that does not fit to next page (or: how to write text with lots of margin notes)?

Tags: floats, marginpar

I analyse an interview transcript and would like to add plenty of notes in the margin. Sometimes these margin notes will not fit on the current page, and thus I would like them to flow to the next page. The `marginfix` package is supposed to fix this, but obviosly I have too many marginpars and LaTeX runs out of memory ("LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.").

I have now searched StackExchange (and Google) in vain; thus I ask the masterminds of LaTeX if a solution is possible?

Comment: Just found basically the same question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63167/how-to-make-sure-the-images-properly-float-on-the-marginpar

Comment: And `\usepackage{morefloats}` is at least a temporary relief from the "Too many unprocessed floats" error from `marginfix`.

Comment: I know it may not fix the problem, but have you tried increasing the margins for the `marginpar` notes? Might ease it a little.

Comment: Yes, @NathanaelFarley, but that is a poor-man's-solution. :-)

Comment: Would placing `\marginpar`s on both margins help your situation?

Comment: Based on the first comment by the OP, marking as a dupe.