# How to manage large sidenotes in tufte-handout class?

Tags: footnotes, marginpar, tufte, sidenotes

Well I was working in a part of a book for a lesson, but I want to *translate* it into a `tufte class`. But my problem is that the document contents a lot of notes. Few of them are very close and are very large. When I compose it with the `\footnote`command I have no problems for spread the text in the necessary pages until finish the note.

As we know all the `\footnotes`are converted in `\sidenotes` in the Tufte classes. So, when that notes are converted I have troubles of a clash between two of then if they are large, but the worst is that few of them don't appear in the page neither in the next one. So, is there a way to compose correctly large notes in a `tufte class` document?

A MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}    
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[english=british,french=quotes,german=quotes,spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

%\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}    

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%output-decimal-marker = {,},
detect-weight= true, 
range-units = brackets,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}

\setlength\marginparpush{14pt}
\morefloats
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\parskip0.4\baselineskip    

\title{Trabajo asalariado y capital}
\author{Karl Marx}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\bigskip

\section{Introducción de Friedrich Engels a la edición de 1891}

\noindent El trabajo que reproducimos a continuación se publicó,\footnote{Al publicar \enquote{Trabajo asalariado y capital}, Marx se proponía describir en forma popular las relaciones económicas, base material de la lucha de clases de la sociedad capitalista. Quería pertrechar al proletariado con la arma teórica del conocimiento científico de la base en que descansan en la sociedad capitalista la dominación de clase de la burguesía y la esclavitud asalariada de los obreros. Al desarrollar los puntos de partida de su teoría de la plusvalía, Marx formula a grandes rasgos la tesis de la depauperación relativa y absoluta de la clase obrera bajo el capitalismo.} bajo la forma de una serie de artículos editoriales, en la \foreignquote{german}{Neue Rheinische Zeitung},\footnote{La \foreignquote{german}{Neue Rheinische Zeitung. Organ der Demokratie} (Nueva Gaceta del Rin. Organo de la Democracia) salía todos los días en Colonia desde el 1 de junio de 1848 hasta el 19 de mayo de 1849; la dirigía Marx, y en el consejo de redacción figuraba Engels.} a partir del 4 de abril de 1849. Le sirvieron de base las conferencias dadas por Marx, en 1847, en la Asociación Obrera Alemana de Bruselas.\footnote{La Asociación Obrera Alemana de Bruselas fue fundada por Marx y Engels a fines de agosto de 1847 con el fin de dar instrucción política a los obreros alemanes residentes en Bélgica y propagar entre ellos las ideas del comunismo científico. Bajo la dirección de Marx y Engels y sus compañeros de lucha, la Asociación se convirtió en un centro legal de agrupación de los proletarios revolucionarios alemanes en Bélgica. Los mejores elementos de la Asociación integraban la Organización de Bruselas de la Liga de los Comunistas. Las actividades de la Asociación Obrera Alemana de Bruselas se suspendieron poco después de la revolución de febrero de 1848 en Francia, debido a las detenciones y la expulsión de sus componentes por la policía belga.} La publicación de estos artículos quedó incompleta; el \enquote{se continuará} con que termina el artículo publicado en el número 269, no se pudo cumplir, por haberse precipitado por aquellos días los acontecimientos: la invasión de Hungría\footnote{Se alude a la intervención de las tropas del zar en Hungría, en 1849, con el fin de sofocar la revolución burguesa en este país y restaurar allí el poder de los Habsburgo austríacos.} por los rusos, las insurrecciones de Dresde, Iserlohn, Elberfeld, el Palatinado y Baden,\footnote{Se trata de las insurrecciones de las masas populares en Alemania en mayo-julio de 1849 en defensa de la Constitución imperial (adoptada por la Asamblea Nacional de Francfort el 28 de marzo de 1849, pero rechazada por varios Estados alemanes). Tenían un carácter espontáneo y disperso y fueron aplastadas a mediados de julio de 1849.} y, como consecuencia de esto, fue suspendido el propio periódico (19 de mayo de 1849). Entre los papeles dejados por Marx no apareció el manuscrito de la continuación.\footnote{Posteriormente, entre los manuscritos de Marx se descubrió un borrador de la conferencia final o de varias conferencias finales sobre el trabajo asalariado y el capital. Era un manuscrito titulado \enquote{Salarios} y llevaba en la tapa las notas: \enquote{Bruselas, diciembre de 1847}. Por su contenido, este manuscrito completa en parte la obra inacabada de Marx \enquote{Trabajo asalariado y capital}. Sin embargo, las partes finales preparadas para la imprenta, de este trabajo, no se han encontrado entre los manuscritos de Marx.}

\end{document}
```

Well I put the part of my document that causes the issues I've mentioned before. As you can see the footnotes are many and large.

Comment: Your example does not compile on my computer. Also, if you do not change the page layout to fit all the material, I do not see how ´tufte-latex´ or any other class can make it work.

Comment: Sorry, I added an extra } and forgot a couple of options. Try again.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile because it has an extra `}` in "Hungría, en} 1849" and, once solved this, it still has `too many unprocessed floats`. Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63167/how-to-make-sure-the-images-properly-float-on-the-marginpar

Comment: Yes, was a mistake when I was pasting the code. But now it's ok, and you can compile it and see the sidenotes and the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `\usepackage{marginfix}` you'll get

[image]

Comment: +1 But really this is a document design problem and @aradnix should reconsider the design, or the text, or both: `tufte` assumes reasonably brief sidenotes: there is a fixed amount of space for them, and all the advantages of the class for the reader are lost in this case. If there must be a worm of text crawling over a mountain of notes, better to use footnotes, surely.

Comment: @PaulStanley: Completely agree with you.

Comment: Well my text is not so brief, in fact I have more paragraphs, and more notes, but not so large. This paragraph I put in the MWE in fact with that 3 large notes is the only one in the text that give me troubles. So, perhaps `tufte`could be a not so bad idea. Thanks. Now this package will be part of my favourites.