# Adjusting figures or images in margins

Tags: floats, marginpar

Say I want figures to be placed in the margins. I have the following code which produces:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,calc,etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2in]{geometry}
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 1.5in
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{exotmp}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{-1.5in}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}
  }% 
  \item\mbox{}\ignorespaces%
}
{\end{list}\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand\MarginFig[4][width=\marginparwidth]{%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\captionof{figure}{#3}
\label{#4}}
}
%To put all marginnotes on the left side only the patch below is implemented
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\reversemarginpar
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to Problem Solving}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The Problem-Solving Process and Strategies}
\lipsum[4-7]
\section{Three Additional Strategies}
\lipsum[5-12]
\begin{exotmp}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{multicols}
\end{exotmp}
\MarginFig{pencil}{description for figure one}{fig:test1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\MarginFig{pencil}{description for figure one}{fig:test2}
\end{document}
```

What is causing the figure not to display correctly and how can this be fixed. I have read this post, [How to make all figures float on the outer margins of two-side document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53120/10898), but haven't been successful in fixing the issue.

PS: On another note, am looking to fix my code above if there are any inconsistences or bad LaTeXing.

Comment: Can you add a note as to what the purpose of the `\patchcmd`'s is.

Comment: @PeterGrill It forces the `marginpar`s to be on the left hand side only but doesn't seem to work in even numbered pages.

Comment: But then what is `\reversemarginpar` for? Also, why is your document not two sided on the first three pages???  Sorry, if these are obvious, this is new territory for me, so trying to learn.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a link to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73102/marginnote-on-left-side-only-using-document-class-book-with-twoside, as an explanation of those patches.  Again, all new to me.

Comment: @PeterGrill I just found my mistake. Instead of using `\marginpar` I should be using `\marginnote.` Thanks again for the input.

Comment: What input?? I was just trying to learn, not show you the answer!! Now how am I supposed to catch up to @David Carlise???  You should provide a self-answer... I'll go back to distracting Gonalzo then. :-)  You sure you don't need to draw arrows from the figures to somewhere on the page ??? :-) I could go for a `\tikzmark` answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ya sure :-) Why not? I do have many questions about those fabulous arrows of yours. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6256/discussion-between-azetina-and-peter-grill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my mistake:

Instead of `\marginpar` in

> ```
> \newcommand\MarginFig[4][width=\marginparwidth]{%
> \marginpar{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
> \captionof{figure}{#3}
> \label{#4}}
> }
> ```

It should be:

```
\newcommand\MarginFig[4][width=\marginparwidth]{%
\marginnote{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
\captionof{figure}{#3}
\label{#4}}
}
```

Simple mistake on my part and of course thanks to @PeterGrill's annoying questions was I able to solve my problem. :-)

Comment: I personally think that these kind of questions should NOT be closed as this is an easy mistake to made -- I think I actually made it a few weeks ago when I first attempted to place text in the margin. So if others make the same mistake, finding an "Duh" answer such as this is helpful.

Comment: Hey, but you forgot to point out that the only reason you were able to see this is because I kept asking annoying questions which made you look at the code again. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill lol :-) Sure thanks to you of course.